# cannot bind LIMIT value within table result set of a statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following which returns all users...from all computers... of a specific user account.  Works great, BUT I want to have a `ORDER BY computers.computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, ?` on the computers table.

I'm fairly new to joins, but have picked it up pretty quickly in the last day or so, but not sure about specific conditions on a table when joins are involved.

The idea is say there are 20 computers in the account... I limit that to only the first 10, for example, in asc order by its `computer_id`... which in turn would only left join the users for those 10 computers and then left join the account on that.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT users.*
    FROM computers
        LEFT JOIN users
            on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id
        LEFT JOIN accounts
            on accounts.account_id = computers.account_id
    WHERE accounts.account_id = ?
");

$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id'], **limit value goes here**));

// return array
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**EDIT:**

In response to Ollie's answer below... I guess I am doing something wrong here because while it does not produce any errors it also produces no result.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT users.*
    FROM (
            SELECT * FROM computers ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, ?
            ) as c
        LEFT JOIN users
            on users.computer_id = c.computer_id
        LEFT JOIN accounts
            on accounts.account_id = c.account_id
    WHERE accounts.account_id = ?
");

$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id'], $_SESSION['user']['licenses']));

// return array
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Bind values are fine and there is data to be returned as confirmed by my original statement ... so it is something with the statement itself.

**The problem :**

> I've narrowed this down to the LIMIT... if I manually enter LIMIT 0,
>   *whatever* in the statement it works.  If I enter LIMIT 0, ? where I bind the value it returns null.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The knack you need is this:

Anywhere you can say `table` in `SELECT ... FROM table AS t` you can also say

```
 SELECT ...
   FROM (
         /* some valid query */
         ) AS t
```

So you need

```
  SELECT ...
    FROM (
          SELECT * FROM computers ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0,?
          ) AS t
    LEFT JOIN  (whatever)
```

That is, you can either name a physical table, or a virtual table (the result set of a query) anywhere you name a table.

That's why Structured Query Language is called *Structured.*

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I must be doing something wrong here as there is no result at all... yet no errors.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with binding within the (computers)... works if I manually enter the limit in the statement, but not with binding.